# How to find the Bit Depth of an image

Tags: image, python-2.7, image-processing

I am trying to get the Statistics of image like width, height,  bands, min, max, mean, stddev etc., 
I could find all of these but however i can't find the Bit Depth of an image.
i could not find any function , is there a way for this ?

Answer (score 7):

"Color depth, also known as bit depth, is either the number of bits used to indicate the color of a single pixel, in a bitmapped image or video frame buffer, or the number of bits used for each color component of a single pixel." [0]

You can check it by checking the data-type. If you are getting a numpy array in python, you can check the data-type with `my_array.dtype`. You probably get either a `uint8` (8 bit/ 1 byte per colour channel) or `uint16` (16 bit / 2 bytes per colour channel) in rare cases. But most images are encoded in uint8.

[0] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth

Comment: Shouldn't uint16 be 16 bit / **1** byte because 16 bit / 2 byte is same as 8 bit / 1 byte ?

Comment: I have written that a long time ago, but I think I inteded it to be read as: `uint8` is 8 bit (or 1 byte), `uint16` is 16 bit (or 2 bytes)